# Highcharts - graph - decades

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to draw a pretty special graph in Highcharts (javascript library). I want the x-axis to have the decades from 1890 to 2010, but the graph data-can be in between these decades (for example 1891 or 1974). Does anyone know how to do this? Or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: you could try setting the `{xAxis:{min:1890,max:2010}}` in the options of the chart when you create it

Comment: Ended up using tickInterval: 10 * 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 to calculate decades and the parseDate to generate the different timestamps for the plots I was having.

Most likely not the best solution, but it works. The easiest would be to just have decades and put the dots in their right years.

Comment: Fix your question title please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `min` and `max` together with `tickInterval` and `minorTickInterval` will do the work.

```
// Start at 1890
min: Date.UTC(1890, 0, 1),

// End at 2010
max: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),

// Tick interval of 10 years
tickInterval: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1) - Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1),

// Minor tick interval of 2
minorTickInterval: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1) - Date.UTC(2008, 0, 1)
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaGHn/)
[image]

Comment: the following code "tickInterval: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1) - Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1),"  helped me a lot, thanks